# Remoção de caractere no servidor Heroku

Tags: java, regex, heroku

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código para substituição de caractere especial

```
public String removerAcentos(String str) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(str.replaceAll(" ", ""), Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
}
```

Quando executo em minha máquina(windows) ele funciona perfeitamente para meu objetivo.

```
ex: Parametro = "SAGRADO CORAÇÃO" retorno = "SAGRADOCORACAO"
```

Quando executo o método pela requisicao ao servidor acontece o seguinte:

```
ex: Parametro = "SAGRADO CORAÇÃO" retorno = "SAGRADOCORAO"
```

Os caracteres especiais são removidos da string

Alguem sabe me dizer o por que, e alguma solução ?

Comment: Ele deve estar pegando a CultureInfo padrão do servidor você deve configuralá na sua aplicação, se seu sistema local está em Pt-br o servidor deve estar em EN

Comment: Essa parte da REGEX faz justamente isso `replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")`, qualquer coisa que ele não considere como `ASCII` **sera removido, não substituído**.
Desta forma você deve verifica, como dito pelo @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba, o que ele considera `ASCII`

Comment: Os grupos POSIX estão em conformidade com o *Unicode case folding* somente quando o flag `(?U)` é usado. Se você não estiver no Android, `.replaceAll("\\P{ASCII}+", "")` deve funcionar para remover todos os caracteres não-ASCII. Veja https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubpc